# How to use .vue files with Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I currently have one application.js file in my Rails app in which I've put all my Vue.js code, as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  if(document.getElementById('dashboard-topbar')) {
    const dashboard = new Vue({
      ... do stuff
    })
  }
  if(document.getElementById('map')) {
    const map = new Vue({
      ... do stuff
    })
  }
  if(document.getElementById('something-else')) {
    const something-else = new Vue({
      ... do stuff
    })
  }
}
```

but I would like to separate these into their own `.vue` files.
What's the recommended way & directory structure for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use `webpack` and you need to configure specific loader for `vue` file and another supporting loader. By googling itself you can find articles to build vue app from scratch(https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vuejs+webpack+starting).

For directory structure you may follow the **vue-cli** (https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)